# how to convert linear16 text-to-speech to audio file

Tags: audio, encoding, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I just started to play with Google Text-To-Speech API. I generated a post request to:

```
https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?fields=audioContent&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

with the following data:

```
{
 "input": {
  "text": "Hola esto es una prueba"
},
 "voice": {
  "languageCode": "es-419"
 },
 "audioConfig": {
  "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
  "speakingRate": 1,
  "pitch": 0
 }
}
```

and I got a 200 response, with the content:

```
{
    "audioContent" : "UklGRn6iCwBXQVZFZm10I...(super long string)"
}
```

I am assuming this is encoded (or decoded, not sure about the naming), but I would like to actually hear what is that "audioContent".

Comment: [Official document](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/text/synthesize#response-body) says that the value of ``audioContent`` is "A base64-encoded string". I posted this as a comment because I'm not sure whether your issue is only this. Also if you want to know the decode method, can you add the tags of language you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) pointed out, the response is indeed Base64. To actually listen the audio, I pasted the base64 encoded string into a file, then ran:

```
base64 -d audio.txt > audio.wav
```

and that made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a .wav file directly using Python,

```py
audio = r['audioContent']

encoded = audio.encode()
array = base64.b64decode(encoded)

with open('test.wav', 'wb') as f:
 f.write(array)
```