# 80 second delay using Google Cloud SpeechRecognition with python 3.9 on RPi3B+

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, speech

I'm using the PyPi code ( https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)

- cleaned up to use *only* Google Cloud SpeechRecognition.
- Google Json Credentials in shell's environment, and working.

I've enabled the Cloud Speech-to-Text API, got the Json credentials, and the service calls ARE hitting the API. The Microphone is fine, and the recording bit happens quickly.

However, its taking fully 80 seconds to perform the API call!

I've monitored the network traffic, and I can see that the API connection kinda sits idle for 78 seconds, and then TX/RXs really fast in the final 2 seconds. How can I speed this up?

Can it be slow-authentication handshake that I might mend?

MORE INFORMATION: My application performs 3 API calls: Google Speech-to-text | Google Translate text-to-text | Google text-to-Speech. Those API Calls ALWAYS take 80 seconds , 20s & 80s respectively.

Thanks a mil!

The delay happens on the 2nd last line here:

```py
print("0 seconds")
try:
    print("Google Cloud Speech thinks you said " + r.recognize_google_cloud(audio)
print("80th second")
```

Comment: I see you're using a third-party library to interact with Google's API. Have you tried using the google library for doing this? It's documented here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-client-libraries

Comment: Oh No! - It's still taking 80 seconds - even with the Google Library... What's next to try?

Comment: what internet speed does your pi have? cause either upload or download may be slow

Comment: Hi - It's got super fast wifi with fibre link.. From monitoring the transaction, there is next to no data flowing for the first 78 seconds, and then it uploads the audio, and responds really quick at the end. I suspect a slow authentication somehow

Comment: could the issue be with the ssl connection? you may be generating a new client cert each time you connect

Comment: @usermajuser you could try anothe stt library,  [like this one](https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT)

Comment: That sounds plausible.. I'll read up on how this may be happening - and will look at STT. thanks for these tips : )  Will let you know how it goes

Comment: I've checked.. I'm not making any obvious mistakes with the Cert. The Google_Credentials.json is set as environment var in the shell, and is being used - apparently correctly, when the Python program is run from the same shell.  The Google APIs register my API calls.  Is this giant latency unique to the Raspberry Pi? I would much rather keep using Google if I can help it!  * * BOUNTY * * 150 Credibility Dollars,  dead or alive.

Comment: Ok. What audio parameters has your audio? Did you hear about the optimal set of them?

Comment: @Vasyl, I am taking the audio directly from the mic using the PyPi SpeechRecognition code - its usually 2 or 3 seconds long. 
I also tried passing the Google API 16,000hz WAV files (Linear16) of ~170KB size, using the Google Library example.
Both Work. Both take exatcly 80 seconds. Tested using WiFi at ~max distance + using wired Ethernet to Fibre router: 80s each - EVERY time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved! It was the SSL certs; bouquets to @Dean Van Greune & @VonC
My fibre router (Sagemcom) was blocking the Pi's SSL certs, or forcing it to a different port, creating massive delays. I remember solving the same problem for JavaMail TLS a while back, and wanting to take the bat to the router ("Office Space"-style).
Swapping to the hotspot on my phone, all this is working faster than the lightiest lightning now.
Thanks for your help & suggestions guys!!!

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> It was the SSL certs; My fibre router (Sagemcom) was blocking the Pi's SSL certs, or forcing it to a different port, creating massive delays

From the troubleshooting steps below, you would find some related to network configuration, SSL/TLS handshake, and detailed network analysis, which should have helped:

- `openssl` to test the SSL connection time to Google's API
- Wireshark, for network-related issues
- changing network environment (which helps to isolate the problem)

---

### Troubleshooting steps

I would assume the Raspberry Pi has a stable network connection. Still, check that DNS settings are optimal for quick resolutions.

```bash
# Check current DNS configuration
cat /etc/resolv.conf

# Change DNS server if necessary (e.g., to Google's 8.8.8.8)
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

You can also measure the SSL connection time to Google's API ([`openssl s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-s_client.html)).

```bash
# Check SSL handshake time
openssl s_client -connect speech.googleapis.com:443
```

Try and [compress the audio file](https://github.com/topics/audio-compression) if it is large, which might reduce upload time.

```py
# Example: Compressing audio file before upload (pseudo-code)
import audio_compression_library
compressed_audio = audio_compression_library.compress(audio)
```

And switch to an [asynchronous recognition approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52755996/6309), if not already using it.

```py
# Example: Asynchronous call to Google Speech-to-Text API (pseudo-code)
recognize_future = r.recognize_google_cloud_async(audio)
result = recognize_future.result()
```

Confirm that the authentication method is efficient and does not cause delays.

[Profile the Python script](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) to identify any bottlenecks.

```bash
# Install profiling tool
pip install line_profiler

# Run the profiler
kernprof -l -v your_script.py
```

---

> I am taking the audio directly from the mic using the PyPi SpeechRecognition code - its usually 2 or 3 seconds long. I also tried passing the Google API 16,000hz WAV files (Linear16) of ~170KB size, using the Google Library example. Both Work. Both take exatcly 80 seconds. Tested using WiFi at ~max distance + using wired Ethernet to Fibre router: 80s each - EVERY time!

That would mean the issue is not related to the audio file format or network speed, but rather something more intrinsic to the interaction between your Raspberry Pi setup and the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API.

Make sure the audio parameters are consistently set to the optimal values for Google's API (e.g., 16kHz sampling rate, Linear16 format).
You could add a step in your Python script to always [convert the audio to this format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54839532/6309) before sending it to the API.

```py
# Example: Converting audio to 16kHz Linear16 format (pseudo-code)
import audio_format_converter
formatted_audio = audio_format_converter.convert_to_linear16(audio, sample_rate=16000)
```

Since the problem persists across different networks, the issue might be with how the API request is constructed or handled. Try reducing the complexity of the request or breaking it down into smaller parts.

There might be specific configurations or limitations within the Raspberry Pi causing the delay. Check for any background processes or resource limitations that could be impacting the performance.

---

> My application performs 3 API calls: Google Speech-to-text | Google Translate text-to-text | Google text-to-Speech. Those API Calls ALWAYS take 80 seconds , 20s & 80s respectively.

The consistent and specific durations of the delays in your application's API calls to Google services (80 seconds for Speech-to-Text, 20 seconds for Translate, and 80 seconds for Text-to-Speech) suggest a pattern that might be rooted in how these calls are handled either on the Raspberry Pi or within the network infrastructure.
Use monitoring tools to observe CPU usage, memory, and network activity on the Raspberry Pi during the API calls. That might reveal resource bottlenecks.

Regarding Google Speech-to-Text (80 seconds delay), as mentioned before, implement asynchronous calls to see if it reduces the wait time. And consider breaking the audio data into smaller segments before sending it to the API, as it might be easier to process smaller chunks more quickly.
Double-check that the audio format and sampling rate are optimized for Google's API.

For Google Translate (20 seconds delay), check if the size of the text being translated affects the response time. Try with shorter and longer texts to see if there is a pattern. Since this service seems to have a shorter delay, it might be more related to network latency. A detailed network analysis might reveal more insights.

And for Google Text-to-Speech (80 seconds delay), test with varying complexities of text to see if it affects the processing time. Similar to Speech-to-Text, make sure the request is optimally formatted and does not contain unnecessary data or headers.

For all three services, the fact that both Speech-to-Text and Text-to-Speech take exactly 80 seconds may indicate a common bottleneck, possibly in the way audio data is handled. Determine how much time is spent processing data locally on the Raspberry Pi versus the time taken in cloud processing and network transmission. That could be done by timing the different stages of your application's workflow.
And verify that your API key is correctly configured and that you are not hitting any usage quotas or limits that might throttle the speed of your requests.

If possible, run the same application on a different platform or device. If the delays significantly differ, it might indicate an issue specific to the Raspberry Pi's hardware or configuration.

Comment: @usermajuser OK. I have edited the answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for these tips - I'll test them this evening. My uploaded audio is usually pretty tiny, 2-3 seconds - but I'll try audio_compression_library + Async + SSL_test first. I did run WireShark on a connection yesterday, but didn't see any obviously mad SSL stuff.     MORE INFORMATION: My application performs 3 API calls: Google Speech-to-text | Google Translate text-to-text | Google text-to-Speech. Those API Calls ALWAYS take 80 seconds , 20s & 80s respectively.

Comment: @usermajuser OK. I have edited the answer to, again, adds some suggestions regarding each services called.